# How to add sequence numbers to row headers

Tags: wpf, silverlight, wpfdatagrid

I want to add autogenerated numbers to the row headers. I am wondering if this is doable by using WPF datagrid?

Answer (score 4):

You can set them when a DataGridRow is loaded in the LoadingRow event

```
<DataGrid ...
          LoadingRow="dataGrid_LoadingRow">

private void dataGrid_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Header = (e.Row.GetIndex()).ToString();
}
```

Comment: @user496949: The EventHandler should be triggered every time a DataGridRow is loaded. What effect do you get, no row numbers at all?

Comment: @user496949: Can you post some code reproducing this problem? I can't get this method to fail even though I tried :)

Comment: Just one line code exatcly as e.Row.Header = (e.Row.GetIndex()).ToString();

Comment: I put the data grid into the Grid Panel

Comment: @user496949: I have it in a Grid to and it works for me. Uploaded my sample project here, maybe you can work out the difference: http://www.mediafire.com/?yrqa9lfw5jkmlpj